Multirow Cell Content is overlapping in Latex with New Line Feature
New Line Feature is not working inside the table, the content is overlapping.

Note: The arraystretch should not also be increased.
How Can i include newline inside the table cell without overlapping.Any ideas or thoughts are much appreciated.
\documentclass[10pt,a3paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2cm,bottom=2.8cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} 
\begin{tabular}{
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.4cm}
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7.5cm}
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{9cm}|} % Adjusted to m{9cm} for dynamic row height
\hline
\textbf{S. No.} & \textbf{Sport} & \textbf{Round} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Score} & \textbf{Event status} & \textbf{Top 5 places} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1} & \multirow{2}{6cm}{Football} & 1 & 03-07-2024 & 8/10 & On Time &
 \multirow{2}{*}{
\makecell{
    {Candidate 1} \\
    {Candidate 2} \\
    {Candidate 3}\\
    {Candidate 4}\\
    {Candidate 5}
    }
    }\\
\cline{3-6} 
& & 2 &  09-07-2024 & 2/5 & On Time & \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{2} & \multirow{3}{6cm}{Cricket} & 1 & 03-07-2024 & 8/10 & On Time &
 \multirow{3}{*}{
\makecell{
    Candidate 1 \\
    Candidate 2 \\
    Candidate 3\\
    Candidate 4\\
    Candidate 5
    }
    }\\
\cline{3-6} 
& & 2 &  09-07-2024 & 2/5 & On Time & \\
\cline{3-6} 
& & 3 &  09-07-2024 & 2/5 & On Time & \\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{3} & \multirow{1}{6cm}{Baseket Ball} & 1 & 03-07-2024 & 8/10 & On Time &
 \multirow{1}{*}{
\makecell{
    Candidate 1 \\
    Candidate 2 \\
    Candidate 3\\
    Candidate 4\\
    Candidate 5
    }
    }\\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{4} & \multirow{1}{6cm}{Badminton} & 1 & 03-07-2024 & 8/10 & Delay &
 \multirow{1}{*}{
\makecell{
    Candidate 1 \\
    Candidate 2 \\
    Candidate 3\\
    Candidate 4\\
    Candidate 5
    }
    }\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Have a look at the tabularray package. It makes it easy to integrate multiline cells in your table.

Like this:

?
With tabularray package this is simple to achieve. Its default features is automatic adoption of multi row cells height to its contents. For other features and packages syntax please see package documentation:
\documentclass[a3paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin={2cm,2.8cm}, hmargin={5cm,0.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c, m, wd=14mm] Q[c, m, wd=75mm] Q[c, m, wd=30mm] Q[c, m, wd=40mm] 
                        Q[c, m, wd=20mm] Q[c, m, wd=50mm] Q[c, m, wd=90mm]},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep  = 3pt, % vertical spaces around cells contents
             vspan = even   % make spanned rows equal height
            }
S. No.      & Sport & Round & Date          & Score & Event status  & Top 5 places          \\
\SetCell[r=2]{} 1           % multirow cell spanning 2 rows
            & \SetCell[r=2]{}  Football  
                    & 1     & 03-07-2024    & 8/10  & On Time       & \SetCell[r=2]{}            
                                                                    {Candidate 1\\
                                                                     Candidate 2\\
                                                                     Candidate 3\\
                                                                     Candidate 4\\
                                                                     Candidate 5}   \\
            &       & 2     &  09-07-2024   & 2/5   & On Time       &               \\
\SetCell[r=3]{} 3   
    & \SetCell[r=3]{}  Cricket
                    & 1     & 03-07-2024    & 8/10  & On Time       & \SetCell[r=3]{}  
                                                                    {Candidate 1\\
                                                                     Candidate 2\\
                                                                     Candidate 3\\
                                                                     Candidate 4\\
                                                                     Candidate 5}   \\   
    &              & 2     &  09-07-2024   & 2/5   & On Time       &               \\            
    &              & 3     &  09-07-2024   & 2/5   & On Time       &               \\
4   &  Basket Ball
                    & 1     & 03-07-2024    & 8/10  & On Time       & {Candidate 1\\
                                                                    Candidate 2\\
                                                                    Candidate 3\\
                                                                    Candidate 4\\
                                                                    Candidate 5}    \\
    5   & Badminton         
                    & 1     & 03-07-2024   & 8/10  & Delay          & {Candidate 1\\
                                                                    Candidate 2\\
                                                                    Candidate 3\\
                                                                    Candidate 4\\
                                                                    Candidate 5}    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

